# How do I get rid of the apostrophe in front of a date-like string when I use google sheets batch update append cell request?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am making a batch update call to google sheets that contains an append cell request. One of the cells I'm updating contains a date-like string 'Oct 2019'.

When I execute the batch update request, google sheets cells have an apostrophe in front of the date-like strings. I looked around in the docs and other methods have an option to include a parameter called 'ValueInputOption' with a value of 'USER_ENTERED' that will remove the apostrophe, but I don't see an option for this in this append cell request. Does anyone know a way to get rid of the apostrophe?

````
'rows': [{'values': [{'userEnteredValue': {'stringValue': 'Aug ' '2019'}},
        {'values': [{'userEnteredValue': {'stringValue': 'Oct ' '2019'}},
        {'values': [{'userEnteredValue': {'stringValue': 'Sep ' '2019'}},
'sheetId': 'N/A'}}]```
````

Comment: Can you provide the script for replicating your issue? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "replace()" Javascript method to remove the apostrophes after the batch execution. For example:

```
  var stringValue = "'Aug ' '2019'";

  var date = stringValue.replace(" ' '"," ");

  Logger.log(date);
```

I'm replacing the 4 characters "`space+apostrophe+space+apostrophe`" with one `space`. This would be a solution, unless you prefer to just not generate them within the batch request. In that case we would need to see your code.